# What is the probability that an arrangement of 'FACETIOUS' begins with A and ends with I?

Tags: probability

In how many ways can the letters of the word FACETIOUS be arranged in a line?
What is the probability that an arrangement begins with A and ends with I ?

I understand the first part which will be $9!= 270725$  since there are $9$ letters in the word.

I'm stuck with that last part, do I have to group the letters and do the combination formula ?

Comment: There  are $7$ letters left, which can be arranged in $7!$ ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many possible ways can the letters be arranged? $9!$
This is all the possible arrangements of the letter.

To use the conditions, you have to put A at the beginning, and you have to put I at the end. Hence you have $7$ letters left to play with. How many ways can you arrange these? $7!$.

So, the probability of interest is 
$$\frac{\text{Arrangements with condition}}{\text{All possible arrangements}} = \frac{7!}{9!} = \frac{1}{9(8)} = \frac{1}{72}.$$